# is gene braintree (4.0.4) supports magento2.4.0?

Tags: magento2.4, braintree, gene-braintree

is gene braintree (4.0.4) supports magento2.4.0?

[image]

Comment: Why you didn't try Magento core BT?

Comment: gene braintree is in built in magento2.4.0